# Wierd output with ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

im new to Java and I'm trying to add an object to ma ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Wizytowka> baza = new ArrayList<Wizytowka>();
int nrTel = 123456789;
Wizytowka nowa = new Wizytowka("imie","nazwisko","nazwaFirmy","mail",nrTel);
baza.add(nowa);
System.out.println("Baza:\n"+baza);
```

But the output is weird and looks like this:

```
Baza:
[com.company.Wizytowka@31cefde0]
```

I really don't know what is wrong. When I try to just output it from object `nowa` with `nowa.wypisz()` it works just fine. Here's how my class "Wizytowka" looks:

```
public class Wizytowka {
private String imie;
private String nazwisko;
private String nazwaFirmy;
private String mail;
private int nrTel;

//imie
public void setImie(String imie){
    this.imie = imie;
}
public String getImie(){
    return this.imie;
}
//nazwisko
public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko){
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
}
public String getNazwisko(){
    return this.nazwisko;
}
//nazwa firmy
public void setNazwaFirmy(String nazwaFirmy){
    this.nazwaFirmy = nazwaFirmy;
}
public String getNazwaFirmy(){
    return this.nazwaFirmy;
}
//mail
public void setMail(String mail){
    this.mail = mail;
}
public String getMail(){
    return this.mail;
}
//nr telefonu
public void setNrTel(int nrTel){
    this.nrTel = nrTel;
}
public int getNrTel(){
    return this.nrTel;
}

public Wizytowka(String imie, String nazwisko, String nazwaFirmy, String mail, int nrTel){
    setImie(imie);
    setNazwisko(nazwisko);
    setNazwaFirmy(nazwaFirmy);
    setMail(mail);
    setNrTel(nrTel);
}

public void wypisz(){
    System.out.println("Imie: "+this.imie);
    System.out.println("Nazwisko: "+this.nazwisko);
    System.out.println("Firma: "+this.nazwaFirmy);
    System.out.println("Mail: "+this.mail);
    System.out.println("Nr tel.: "+this.nrTel);
}
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: You need to add a toString() implementation to your class Wizytowka

Comment: You need to implement a proper `toString()` method, i.e. override the one from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

override toString() method as below :-

```
   @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Wizytowka [imie=" + imie + ", nazwisko=" + nazwisko + ", nazwaFirmy=" + nazwaFirmy + ", mail=" + mail
            + ", nrTel=" + nrTel + "]";
}
```

---

```
public class Wizytowka {
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    private String nazwaFirmy;
    private String mail;
    private int nrTel;

    //imie


public Wizytowka(String imie, String nazwisko, String nazwaFirmy, String mail, int nrTel){
    setImie(imie);
    setNazwisko(nazwisko);
    setNazwaFirmy(nazwaFirmy);
    setMail(mail);
    setNrTel(nrTel);
}

public void wypisz(){
    System.out.println("Imie: "+this.imie);
    System.out.println("Nazwisko: "+this.nazwisko);
    System.out.println("Firma: "+this.nazwaFirmy);
    System.out.println("Mail: "+this.mail);
    System.out.println("Nr tel.: "+this.nrTel);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Wizytowka [imie=" + imie + ", nazwisko=" + nazwisko + ", nazwaFirmy=" + nazwaFirmy + ", mail=" + mail
            + ", nrTel=" + nrTel + "]";
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `toString` method of your class `Wizytowka`, if you want to see content of object (not it's class name and address, as in default `toString` implementation used from `Object` class).
There are more details in [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring).

To avoid boilerplate code you may want to use [`@ToString` feature from lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString).